# Search Store products by modifiers

Tags: expresso-store, low-search

I'm building a shoe store using Expresso Store. Each product will use product modifiers to specify the sizes and colors that are available for that product. The user needs to be able to search/filter products by these modifiers (e.g. *I want a pair of **black** shoes in a size **12***).

Low Search is my go-to search module and looks like it is compatible with Store, but it doesn't appear to support the searching of modifiers.  Likewise, Store's native Search tag doesn't seem to allow searching of modifiers.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how this might be achieved? It seems like the kind of functionality a lot of stores would require - I'm surprised it's not possible.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated [Low Search Store](https://github.com/low/low_search_store), which allows for basic filtering by modifier. See the readme on Github for usage pointers. That should get you going for a bit at least:

```
{exp:low_search:results store:mod:color="black" store:mod:size="12"}
```

...or the dynamic equivalent, of course.